# Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, repository

While experimenting with Grails 3 under IntelliJ I found the following warning:

```
 Unindexed remote maven repositories found. Disable...
 The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: 
 https://repo.grails.org/grails/core
 If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories artifacts,
 Open Repositories List, select required repositories and press "Update" button (show balloon)
```

If I am trying to resolve an issue, I get next error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist in IntelliJ
```

[image]

I would prefer to know, what does it mean? If repository is marked as "remote", then why the problem is absence of some (local?) file?

**UPDATE**

I think this is not related with Grails actually.

How to know more details on error, occurring in `Indexed Maven Repositories` Window in IntelliJ on `Update` button?

The popup message says

`Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist in IntelliJ`

[image]

Answer (score 15):

- If you're using your custom repository
- AND it is Nexus 3.x

chances are high that you forgot to set up a *Task* to publish your maven repository indexes.

Log in via browser. 
Go to Administration/System/Tasks/Create Task/Create Publish Maven indexes Task

Set it for an hourly publish. Done.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue in version 2019.1...is there a way after setting up the task to verify that the index is created?

Comment: Verify that the index is created for your repositories:

`http://10.100.254.13:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-public/.index/
http://10.100.254.13:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-snapshots/.index/
http://10.100.254.13:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-releases/.index/`

I was experiencing this issue but after some time things started to work in 2019.1 and .2.

Comment: Why do I have to use nexus in the intellij+maven integration?

Comment: Sir, you are a savior! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

For me the solution was to delete the folder ~/.m2/repository. This made Maven to re-index everything correctly.

Failed trials, that may work for someone else:

- Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Maven → Repositories : Selecting the repositories and click updates.
- Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Maven: Giving more memory JVM
- Delete folder ~/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/caches

Answer (score 3):

You can try using grails/repo and grails/plugins instead of grails/core.

For example, in build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins' }
}
```

I tested on IntelliJ Community 15 with Grails 3.0.9, JVM Version: 1.8.0_45, Apache Maven 3.3.9 and Gradle 2.3.

Answer (score 2):

The same error occurs for Artifactory users. Solved with sanya's hint. Make sure the local repositories are included.
[image: Artifactory Indexing]

After that the repo works:
[image]

Comment: I found it under Admin, Services, Maven Indexer. I had to enable the Maven Indexer, then add the repositories to "Included Repositories", then click "Save", then click "Run Indexing Now". Trying to run indexing before saving indexed nothing, since there were no included repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I've had faulty indexes after fresh install (from Snap ubuntu).

It has been solved by changing the MAVEN HOMe PATH [image: MAVEN HOME PATH]
I've switched from "bundled" to "/usr/share/maven"

None of the solutions aforementioned solved my issue in my case