# Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, settings

I'm using a remote **artifactory** repo.
I added this repo to settings.xml file which was placed in the `<user>/.m2/` folder:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <name>artifactory</name>
            <url>http://example.com/artifactory/repo</url>
            <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>snapshots-only</name>
                    <url>http://example.com/artifactory/snapshots-only</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

In Idea settings in the "Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories" page I see URL to my artifactory repo. But when I click on "Update" button, I get error message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist

How to solve this trouble?

Windows 8
Maven 3.2.1
Idea 2017.1.5

Comment: [Check this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000125290-Indexing-https-plugins-gradle-org-m2?page=1#community_comment_115000160950).

Comment: I was research google pages before asking my question. I was found this page, but it's doesn't help me

Comment: What help are you looking for? Your repository doesn't support indexing, therefore the only option is to disable the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bumping the memory for the importer then restarting the IntelliJ? (worked for me)

Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Maven → Importing → VM options for importer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394767/2242239